# Is there a way to run a .Net application without running windows?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I've got a .Net application that runs as a service. I'd like to run it on a machine that is dedicated to that service. For other machines that have a very dedicated purpose, I use instance of Windows Server Core. But from what I've read and seen, Windows Server Core doesn't support .Net.

Is there away to run a .Net application without running a full blown version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific application, you may be able to run it using Mono. Mono lets you run most .NET programs. You can check the application's compatibility with Mono using [this tool](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

If your application can run on Mono, you can try installing it on your Windows Server Core. If it doesn't work, there's always many, *many* lightweight versions of Linux that can run Mono. I won't make any specific recommendations here, as I don't use them myself.

Edit: If you are running Windows Server Core 2008 **R2**, there's a [cut down version of .NET for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770052%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx), but [some features may be missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). An additional [standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22833) is available.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [.Net Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/default.aspx) which is a very limited version of the .Net framework/runtime for embedded devices. To my knowledge, it doesn't require Windows.
Wikipedia, as always, has [additional information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework).

Comment: Can it run on a PC or does it have to run on an embedded device?

Comment: I've never worked with it myself. There are also other [alternative implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Alternative_implementations).